# Why is array of chars printing one less char than needed after dynamically allocating memory with malloc()?

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

The problem I am facing is that if I enter in 5 characters into an array using a loop that scanf's each character separately it only prints out 4 of the characters in the array (using a loop again). This problem does not arise if I do not dynamically allocate memory to the array.

```
 int main() {

    int nchars = 0;
    char* arr = NULL; 


    printf("Enter number of characters you want in string: "); scanf("%d", &nchars);

    arr = (char*)malloc(nchars * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter characters you want in the array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nchars; ++i) {
        scanf("%c\n", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nchars; ++i) {
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal:

```
Enter number of characters you want in string: 5
Enter characters you want in the array:
a
m
i
i
i

amii (output)
```

If I do not put a \n after the %c in the scan statement it only scans two chars and outputs them on new lines like this:

```
Enter number of characters you want in string: 5
Enter characters you want in the array:
a
m

a
m
```

I have tried different variations where I would create a temp array and strcpy() to the dynamically allocated char arr but still nothing. As well as:

```
arr = (char*)malloc((nchars + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

To see if allocating one more byte would add the last letter.

Comment: nchars is 0 when you do malloc()

Comment: this would be a good time to point out that you should check the return status of `malloc`.  In this case, it would have returned `NULL` because you tried to pass in a size of `0`.

Comment: @SteveSummit sorry that was my mistake when adding my code. It was originally the right way around and still not working.

Comment: Okay, now I'll bring back my first comment.  Is the issue that you aren't taking into account that you need space for the terminating NULL character?

Comment: @Ami Please figure out a way to copy and paste *exactly* the code you're running on your computer.  If you're retyping it, it's too easy to make a mistake which means we're not seeing what your compiler is seeing which makes it *impossible* to debug!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons from the way it's printed (character by character) it looks like the null terminator isn't required.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yep sorry, I did that orginally but when I was showing different iteraltions I messed around with it rathar than recopying all my iterations. My mistake I will make sure to not do that again. The code I have right now is the exact code I am running to make that clear to all!

Comment: Ah, okay, running it in a debugger found the problem quickly.  `\n` is the first character being read into the array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons if you don't mind me asking, what debugger are you using or how? I am currently at the end of a beginner level C class at my university and the prof has not mentioned debugging c code other than simply reading over lines and some simple tags in cygwin terminal

Comment: gdb is the go-to debugger for C/C++ on linux (and I imagine cygwin supports it too). It has a bit of a learning curve especially for beginner programmers but it's definitely worth it. Most IDEs like visual studio come with their own built in debugger. Other than that there's also the usual method of adding lots of `printf` statements everywhere.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons *In this case, it would have returned `NULL` because you tried to pass in a size of `0`.*  No. Per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.1), the return value of `malloc()` when passed zero bytes is **unspecified**:  "The following are unspecified: ... The amount of storage allocated by a successful call to the calloc, malloc, or realloc function when 0 bytes was requested"  When passed zero, `malloc()` is free to return `NULL` or a pointer to a zero-byte buffer.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is resolved, but the other solution that must be mentioned is *don't use scanf*.  In this case, plain `getchar` would be easier and more straightforward in every way.  (And IMO there are virtually no uses of `scanf` that are preferable to their more reliable, non-scanf alternatives.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see.  I was relying on the man-pages which said `NULL may also be returned by a successful call to malloc() with a size of zero`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons *I was relying on the man-pages which said ...* That means your implementation has specified what happens.  Different implementations are free to behave differently, and the implementation in use here isn't clearly identified, if it's identified at all.

Comment: @Ami As Kevin mentioned, GDB is the go-to.  While starting out, you'll likely be more comfortable working in an IDE which should have built in support for debugging tools.  With a debugger you'll be able to step through code a line at a time and take a peek at the states of variables.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `scanf("%d", ...)` leaves the newline character in the input stream. When you get to the `scanf("%c\n", ...)` it reads the newline and the character you typed stays in the input stream, meaning you're off by one. You'll notice that in your output there's a blank line before `amii` is printed.

The solution is to have `scanf` skip whitespace. Change your loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nchars; ++i) {
    scanf(" %c", &arr[i]);
}
```

Putting a space before the `%c` means *skip leading whitespace*.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thank you good sir! I would have never thought of that.